# How can I use a Delphi (2007) control in a WinForms application?

Tags: winforms, delphi, delphi-2007

We have an existing and complex control in Delphi 2007, and we would like to reuse that control in a WinForms application. Did anyone made this work in the past? What would be the best approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can WinForms use an ActiveX?  If so, you should be able to make an ActiveX with the VCL in it.  I think I used to know how to do that.

Comment: This does require some rewriting of the control, but is the only thing I can think of. (I wonder how much...)

Answer (score 2):

you can do that using the [`RemObjects Hydra 3.0`](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/mixedmode.aspx) components